# Create user interface for gdal2tiles

Tags: python, gdal2tiles

I am trying to create UI for gdal2tiles which select a Tiff File then use it as gdal2tiles input. I am using Django for backend.
but there is a problem in read image.
[image]

Here is my HTML code:

```
 <form action="{% url 'upload' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="input-group">
 <input name="myfile" type="file" class="form-control" id="inputGroupFile04" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04" aria-label="Upload">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="inputGroupFileAddon04">Upload</button>
                </div>

            </form>
```

and here is GDAL:

```py
def uploadFile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.FILES['myfile'].read()
        options = {'zoom': 9, 'resume': True, 'processes': 2}
        gdal2tiles.generate_tiles(file, '/export', **options)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Access Denied!!!!')
```

Comment: Please include the error [in your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/465246/edit) as text.